Altium displays "inverted" colours on PCB
I’m in a bit of a hurry for my next prototype and of course Altium had to make it challenging.
For some reason Altium displays all colours on the PCB as inverted, with some exceptions notably the 3D view shows the board to be green, even thought the tin of the solder appears with a diluted cyan tint.
Also the colours arent really inverted, its just that red appears blue and vice versa, ive even tried to change layer colors to something outside the default color scheme but the tint persists.

EDIT: Added screenshot upon request


also this weird tint/negative effect applies to the guides/grid, silkscreen, but strangly does not affect the 3d model nor the square representing the 3d model, the schematic files are all fine

Ive tried to delete preferences and also uninstalling everything, opening a different project, deleting the pcb and starting from scratch nothing seems to work regarding more destructive methods

Could you post a proper screenshot with View configuration panel visible?

Not really a solution but have you tried downloading and installing a slightly earlier version of AD?

What version of AD are you using, anyway? Thats relevant info for a question like this.

@MrGerber yes, give me some minutes, also i've tried both AD23 but now i've updated to AD24 at the latest version 24.7(i think)

Also about the image i added i use a program to provide a tiling effect and im on a virtual machine but i believe this shouldn't cause any issues as altium seems to sometimes acurately draw colours

I’m voting to close this question because this is not the Altium support desk.

@brhans i guess so, its just that altium support is broken(at least for me) and i've seen multiple highly upvoted questions regarding altium itself

I have the same problem. It started with 23.8. I updated to 24.7 and I still have it. But when I installed Altium on another computer, it works fine. But when I removed and reinstalled it on my primary computer, the problem persists. These are my very first days using Altium (I hate it with all my being; KiCad is MUCH better), but as far as I remember the problem was not present from the beginning, but it started at some point. Maybe after my VirtualBox with Altium crashed a few times. I'm not sure.

Ok, I've found the reason of the problem in my case. It was because I enabled 3D acceleration in VirtualBox. This caused inverted layer colors in Altium, as well as other various strange behavior, plus a lot of crashes. It seems that I will have to use Altium in native Windows. I hate it even more now.

@Manx i havent tested it out but if it fixes it please type in as a response as it seems very plausible

@Imeguras Thanks for the heads up! I missed your comment that you also use a virtual machine. In such case I'm confident the 3D acceleration is the culprit.

It's the 3D acceleration in VirtualBox. I guess Altium doesn't play well with it.
In my case, besides the inverted colors, there was various other strange behavior while editing the PCB, plus a lot of crashes, especially while trying to use the 3D view or refill polygons.
The solution is to disable the 3D acceleration according to the screenshot below. Unfortunately this makes moving/zooming the PCB very slow. Too slow. I'm afraid using native Windows is the only, albeit very unfortunate, real solution.


I've now tested it and not only was i finally able to open my project which at this point causes a lot of problems even on bare metal windows machines but it fixes the colours.
